# Unable to add parameters to Spring OAuth2UserRequest

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I want to be able to pass additional parameters from the client to the OAuth2 user service.  Following this Spring reference https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2Client-authorization-request-resolver, I am able to add the additional parameter to the OAuth2AuthorizationRequest.  When I try to retrieve the parameter in my custom DefaultOAuth2UserService it is no longer part of the OAuth2UserRequest.

I think the issue is related to the resolve method of OAuth2AuthorizationRequest being called twice, the second time the authorizationRequest is null.  See debug log below

Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot / fix this issue?

Client Request

```
http://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorize/github?redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/oauth2/redirect&action=signup
```

Detailed Log

```
CustomAuthorizationRequestResolver : in CustomAuthorizationRequestResolver.resolve() authorizationRequest is [Initialized]
CustomAuthorizationRequestResolver: action parameter from HttpServletRequest is [signup]
CustomAuthorizationRequestResolver: number of additional parameters added to OAuth2AuthorizationRequest is [1]
CustomAuthorizationRequestResolver: in CustomAuthorizationRequestResolver.resolve() authorizationRequest is [null]
CustomOAuth2UserService: in CustomOAuth2UserService.loadUser() size of additional parameters [0]
```

CustomAuthorizationRequestResolver

```
public class CustomAuthorizationRequestResolver implements OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver {
    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomAuthorizationRequestResolver.class);
    private final OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver defaultAuthorizationRequestResolver;

    public CustomAuthorizationRequestResolver(ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
        this.defaultAuthorizationRequestResolver = new DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver(clientRegistrationRepository,
                "/oauth2/authorize");
    }

    @Override
    public OAuth2AuthorizationRequest resolve(HttpServletRequest request) {
        OAuth2AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest = this.defaultAuthorizationRequestResolver.resolve(request);
        logger.debug("in CustomAuthorizationRequestResolver.resolve() authorizationRequest is [{}]", 
            authorizationRequest == null ? "null" : "Initialized");
        return authorizationRequest != null ? customAuthorizationRequest(request, authorizationRequest) : null;
    }

    @Override
    public OAuth2AuthorizationRequest resolve(HttpServletRequest request, String clientRegistrationId) {
        OAuth2AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest = this.defaultAuthorizationRequestResolver.resolve(
                request, clientRegistrationId);
        return authorizationRequest != null ? customAuthorizationRequest(request, authorizationRequest) : null;
    }

    private OAuth2AuthorizationRequest customAuthorizationRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
            OAuth2AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest) {
        String action = request.getParameter("action");
        logger.debug("action parameter from HttpServletRequest is [{}]", action);

        Map<String, Object> additionalParameters = new LinkedHashMap<>(authorizationRequest.getAdditionalParameters());
        additionalParameters.put("action", action);

        OAuth2AuthorizationRequest rtn = OAuth2AuthorizationRequest.from(authorizationRequest).additionalParameters(
                additionalParameters).build();

        logger.debug("number of additional parameters added to OAuth2AuthorizationRequest is [{}]", rtn.getAdditionalParameters()
                .size());

        return rtn;
    }
}
```

CustomOAuth2UserService

```
public class CustomOAuth2UserService extends DefaultOAuth2UserService {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomOAuth2UserService.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public OAuth2User loadUser(OAuth2UserRequest oAuth2UserRequest) throws OAuth2AuthenticationException {
        OAuth2User oAuth2User = super.loadUser(oAuth2UserRequest);

        logger.debug("in CustomOAuth2UserService.loadUser() size of additional parameters [{}]", oAuth2UserRequest
                .getAdditionalParameters().size());
        // other processing
    }
    
    // other methods
}
```

Comment: The `OAuth2AuthorizationRequest` and `OAuth2UserRequest` are different requests to different endpoints. `OAuth2AuthorizationRequest` represents the request to `http://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorize/github?redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/oauth2/redirect&action=signup`, and `OAuth2UserRequest` represents the request to, for example, `http://localhost:3000/userinfo`. The additional parameter was never part of the `OAuth2UserRequest`.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance!   It helped me refine both my understanding of the OAuth process and improve how I handle business requirements.  I traced back through the example code I was using and realized that the client made a redirect to the profile page.  

If you post your comment as an answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OAuth2AuthorizationRequest` and `OAuth2UserRequest` are different requests to different endpoints.

The `OAuth2AuthorizationRequest` represents the request to `http://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorize/github?redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/oauth2/redirect&action=signup`, while the `OAuth2UserRequest` represents the request to, for example, `http://localhost:3000/userinfo`.

The additional parameter was never part of the `OAuth2UserRequest`.